# jQuery .on() Method Not Detecting Future Elements

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to use jQuery in order to populate one dropdown based on the selection of the dropdown before it, like so:

[image: dropdown]

This works fine for the *first* row, however I'm using WordPress' Gravity Forms plugin to let me add subsequent rows. My jQuery script seems to get completely ignored by any dropdowns that are added after the page is loaded.

Here is how I'm using the method:

```
$('#form-register .gfield_list tr td:first select').on('change', function() {
    var fieldBrand = $(this).parent().next().find('select');
    alert('1');
```

The '1' is only alerted in the select field in the first row, no others.

You can see the web page (with the full jQuery script) here:
- http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~devappli/register/

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I see no errors in Firefox's Error Console.

Also I'm having the same problem with the tooltips I've applied to the +/- icons, these aren't as important but I imagine the cause of the problem is the same.

Answer (score 6):

`on` only affects future elements when event delegation is used.  You should read the [delegation section of the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).  Something like this will work assuming `#form-register` is never loaded through ajax.

```
$('#form-register').on('change', '.gfield_list tr td:first select', function() {
```

Comment: Alternatively, if it is, you can bind the event to `document` which is always available.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you are supposed to use delegated events. You need to provide a selector for future elements.

Assuming `#form-register` exist at bind time, try with this

```
$('#form-register').on('change', '.gfield_list tr td:first select', function() { 
... 
})
```

`#form-register` can be replaced by any container that exist at bind time, you should try to pick the closest available in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I fixed it in the end however with:
`$(document).on('change','#form-register .gfield_list tr td:first-child select', function() {`